# Running the same task with different priorities using Celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

So I have a pretty interesting scenario where I want to run the same Celery task with different priorities, depending on where it's called - for example, I want to run a task for premium users with a higher priority than for non-premium users.

Using the docs I was able to set up multiple queues and was able to get this to work by changing all my .delay calls to .apply_async calls and passing in an additional routing_key specifying the priority queue. The problem is having to do this in a ton of different places. Is there a better way to handle this? I'm trying to avoid changing the code in my views as much as possible and would prefer to handle this within the tasks or celery configuration.

Comment: why not make it different tasks?

Comment: Then I'd have the same logic duplicated so I'm trying to avoid that. Another idea I had was passing in additional argument to the task to indicate the priority and writing a Task Router to use that in determining which routing key to pass.

Comment: make it a separate function, you have def func(params) and in both tasks you can invoke the same function. It's easier to unit test too.

Comment: Ah I see. So I'm basically creating a common function and then having two different functions call it. Seems like overkill but makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, i don't like it much neither. But, down the road it's easier to administer and to track. It's a pragmatic solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use partial evaluation instead of defining separate tasks.

```
from celery.task import task
from functools import partial

@task
def do_something():
    pass

premium_do_something = partial(do_something.apply_async, routing_key="premium")

do_something.async_apply()
premium_do_something()
```

Comment: Ah this is pretty clever. This cuts down the tasks I'm defining from 3 to 2. The base task will use the default routing key and the premium will pass it's own along. Is there a way to do this using .delay vs .apply_async - based on the docs it looks as if only .apply_async accepts the routing_key argument.

Comment: delay is only for simple cases. It doesn't accept routing_key.